# Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckfinder

i want to use Ckeditor and Ckfinder thgother in angular .

i u use by this way :

**Module :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**and this is my component :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;



  ngOnInit(): void {

    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [CKFinder],

        // Enable the "Insert image" button in the toolbar.
        toolbar: ['uploadImage' ],

        ckfinder: {
          // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
          uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
        }
      });

  }


}
```

**and this is Html Code :**

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading','ckfinder', '|', 'bold', 'italic' ] }"
  data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

but it show me this error:

> Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

**whats the problem ? how can i use the Ckfinder in angular ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official CK Editor 5 Angular component.

Documentation: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

GitHub:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

You can create a custom build using [Online Builder tool](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) with all the required plugins and then import that build in angular.

I have been using the custom build with custom plugins without any issues.